# taking doubles out of a specific string

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11

All my strings will be formatted such as

```
std::string templine;
templine = "vertex 4.5 2.2 1";
```

something of that sort. of course different doubles will be input but vertex will always be there
I tried `stod` but I just don't know what to do.

just to test it I did this:

```
    std::string orbits = "Vertex 4.5 2.3 5";
double x,y,z;
std::size_t offset = 0;

z = std::stod(&orbits[7], &offset);
y = std::stod(&orbits[offset+2]);
x = std::stod(&orbits[offset+2]);

std::cout << "z " << z << std::endl;
std::cout << "y " << y << std::endl;
std::cout << "x " << x << std::endl;
```

it gives me this error

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stod
Aborted

Comment: Use `stringstream`, then you can read the first word into a throwaway string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to handle this is to load the string into a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and then use its `operator >>` to extract the different parts.  In the example I use a dummy string called `eater` that is used to extract the `"Vertex"` part out of the string.

```
std::stringstream ss(orbits)
std::string eater;
ss >> eater; //consumes "Vertex"
ss >> x >> y >> z; // gets the doubles
```

We could even scope the extraction part so that the temporary `string` and `stringstream` only exist for the extraction like

```
{
    std::stringstream ss(orbits)
    std::string eater;
    ss >> eater; //consumes "Vertex"
    ss >> x >> y >> z; // gets the doubles
}
// now ss and eater are gone and x, y and z are populated.
```

You could also do this as a function if you do not like free scopes like that.